# Memory padding issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working on a sample application in this application I am serializing some of the data. In client application I am reading the serialized data back. While doing this I observed some strange behavior.

In sample application size of object is different from size of data in client. I think this is because of memory padding. My problem is I am trying to write “BRUSHOBJ” to file. This structure is defined by Microsoft. I can change the declaration of this structure. Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Please let me know how to apply memory padding on slandered data type.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to just cast the address of a `struct` to
`char*`, and use `ostream::write` on it.  This simply doesn't work.
There's padding, but there's also the size of different types (which
varies from one platform to the next), byte order, and on some more
exotic platforms (including most mainframes) data representation itself.
Generally, you need a specification of what the output data should look
like, byte by byte, and you have to then write each byte with the
required value.

And this is just for simple types.  A quick glance at BRUSHOBJ shows
that it contains a pointer, which you'll probably have to
follow—you'll certainly have to do something with it, since the
receiving end won't be able to do anything with a pointer into your
data.  (I suspect, given the description, that you'll have to convert it
into some sort of identifier, and also transmit a dictionary mapping
such identifiers to objects.  But I don't know enough about how this
structure is used to be sure.)

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options

- serializing data
- modify memory padding via #pragma pack

**Serializing** data has no relation with memory padding, you are just defining a way to write/ read back memory to/from a memory location (the memory stream).

I see the that _BRUSHOBJ struct has the following definition,

```
typedef struct _BRUSHOBJ {
  ULONG  iSolidColor;
  PVOID  pvRbrush;
  FLONG  flColorType;
} BRUSHOBJ;
```

please note that sending a pointer across process is nonsens. serializing a pointer should be done by writing the size of memory and the the memory itself. Anyway if you want to pass this BRUSHOBJ to a windows function you can get undefined behavior. It's not a supported/documented way of passing a BRUSHOBJ across process.

**memory padding** can by applied like this

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(4)
struct myStruct
{
   char Char1
   int Int1;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

If you what to modify padding you should doit for a structure that is written by you.